# Locate features along routes when features are parallel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing

I am trying to use Esri's Linear Referencing Tool to conform a drawn line to a road route.  I have a fairly large search radius of 20m.

As long as the line I draw touches the route at some point, the tool works as I would expect.  The odd behavior is when the drawn line is parallel to the route.  Then no matter how close I draw my line to the route nothing gets referenced.

How does one get the linear referencing tool to find a line parallel to a route?
[image: Line drawn touching route]
[image: Line drawn parallel to route]

The purple is my route. the green is a road allowance that is 20M wide.

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using?  I normally don't use this tool with lines.  I extract the end points of a polyline feature with the line's ObjectID in a calculated field and use Locate Feature Along Route for them, then join the measures back to the event.  There is a way to sort events and use ObjectID + 1 in a field to join the From and To measure back together to recreate the line event.

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.3 standard.

Comment: Would you calculate the coordinates of the end points, export the table and make a point feature class of the end points?  Then using the calculated point fc locate those to the route and use them as the Fmeas and Tmeas?

Comment: You are correct, but you may want to use the Feature Vertices to Points tool with the Both Ends option.  The ObjectID of the line or some other unique line ID has to be in a permanent field before the X/Y table or points are created, so that the start and end point can be joined back together.  Feature Vertice to Points with Both Ends generates From then To measures, so with a Modulus of 2 you can calculate a field to separate the From and To points of the line in case line direction matters to you, otherwise you can just use Summary Statistics to get Min/Max as From/To for each ObjectID.